How to reconcile the difference between two arrays with a unique tagging?
I have 2 sheets in my excel with arrays of names tagged to and ID but the names are not in the same order and can be jumbled up at times. I would like to find out if those names appear in the second sheet with the same tagging or not.
I was trying to do a lookup/match but that doesn't seem to do the trick, wondering if anyone could provide some insights on this? Preferably an explanation to the formula too so I could learn a thing or two! Thanks in advance.
Here are the examples of the sheet in question. i.e., How do I flag out that in ID456, Hank is not in the second sheet.
Sheet1



ID
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5




123
John
David
Jane
Nelson
Dean


456
Audrey
Hazel
Hank




789
Tom
Dick
Harry





Sheet2



ID
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5




123
Dean
David
John
Nelson
Jane


456
Hazel
Audrey





789
Harry
Tom
Dick













Have tried to use lookup functions/match/xmatch but can't seem to quite get it.

Could you share some relevant sample data using this table markdown generator so we have something to work with. Simply copy not more than 21 relevant rows (including the headers) of a table into the website's text box, press Submit, press Copy and paste it into your post (question).

Hi there, I have edited the post but I am not certain if that's what you're looking for? Appreciate your help nonetheless! :)

Thanks. Just a new line between the title and the table was missing.

Would you be interested in listing the unique names?: =LET(x,LAMBDA(id,name,TOCOL(IFS(LEN(name),id&"|"&name),2)),TEXTAFTER(UNIQUE(VSTACK(x(Sheet1!A2:A4,Sheet1!B2:F4),x(Sheet2!A2:A4,Sheet2!B2:F4)),,1),"|")) or removing the TEXTAFTER part results in the ID|Name

Conditional Formatting: A Double Match

Select Sheet1!B2:F4.

Select Home-->Styles-->Conditional Formatting-->New Rule-->Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

Enter the following formula:
=AND(B2<>"",ISERROR(MATCH(B2,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$F$4,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0),),0)))


Select a fill color.

You can also enter this formula into a cell e.g. B6 and expand as required. That's how it was created.




Hey man, thanks for this! However, after I tried it on my spreadsheet and tweaking it to the same context, it seemed like all the fields in my "Names" becomes highlighted instead. Not too sure if this works for me :/

=AND(B2<>"",ISERROR(MATCH(B2,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$P$9075,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9075)))))
It's a large sheet that expands to Column P and Row 9000+... so this was what I used.

You lost the commas and zeros at the end of the formula.

Omg, so foolish of me. It seems like it works now! I'll do some sanity check but so far so good, thanks a bunch man!

I would suggest using Power Query and its built in tools to handle lists (assuming your input tables are named "Table1" and "Table2":
let
    // Load Table1 and unpivot to create a single column of values
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    UnpivotedTable1 = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source1, {}, "Column", "Value"),
    
    // Convert unpivoted values from Table1 to a list
    List1 = UnpivotedTable1[Value],

    // Load Table2 and unpivot to create a single column of values
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    UnpivotedTable2 = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source2, {}, "Column", "Value"),
    
    // Convert unpivoted values from Table2 to a list
    List2 = UnpivotedTable2[Value],

    // Find items in List1 that are not in List2
    NonMatchingItems = List.Difference(List1, List2)

in 
    NonMatchingItems

Assuming you have Excel 365 you could also use the following formula:
=LET(
    Array1, TOROW(Table1),
    Array2, TOROW(Table2),

    DiffArray, FILTER(Array1, (ISNA(MATCH(Array1, Array2, 0))) * (Array1 <> 0)),

    DiffArray
)


Hi Michal, thank you so much for your assistance but this doesn't seem to work for me. I can't seem to grasp the concept either, do you reckon there's a formula I could use on another sheet to get the output I want?
